# Showing that if $\partial E \subset E$, then E is closed.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show that if $\partial E \subset E$, then E is closed.

My proof is the following.

To show $E$ is closed, we need to show that $E = \bar E$. So, pick some $x \in \partial E$, then since by definition we know that $\partial E = \overline E \cap \overline{E^c}$, then we have that $x \in \overline E$ and $x \in \overline{E^c}$. Thus, we have that, since $x \in \partial E \subset E$, then $\overline E \subset E$, but we also know that $E \subset \overline{E}$, so we can conlude that $E=\overline E$, and therefore $E$ is closed.

Is this proof right? Thanks!

Comment: It's even simpler, since $\partial E \subset E$, we know $E = E \cup \partial E$. Then probably your definition of the closure of a set is $\bar E = E \cup \partial E$. Thus $E = \bar E$.

Comment: You make a mistake when you say that since $x\in\partial E\subset E$, then $\overline E \subset E$. This is not true from what you've written. You only considered points in the intersection of $\overline E$ and its complement, you need to consider an arbitrary point in $\overline E$, possible not in the intersection, if you want to say $\overline E\subset E$. It's a simple fix, though, so you've essentially got it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know already that $\overline{E} = E \cup \partial E$ then it's trivial: $\overline{E} = E \cup \partial E \subseteq E \cup E = E \subseteq \overline{E}$ and we have equality and $E$ is closed.

If not, pick $x \in \overline{E}$. If $x \notin E$, then every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $E^c$ (in $x$) and $E$ (as $x \in \overline{E}$) and then $x \in \partial E \subseteq E$, contradiction (as $x \notin E$ implies $x \in E$). So in fact $x \in E$, and the inclusion is shown.

I don't understand the structure of your proof: you want $\overline{E} \subseteq E$ as well, but to show that, you need to start with an arbitary element of $\overline{E}$, not $\partial E$ (unless you already know $\partial E \cup E = \overline{E}$ and then my first proof is shorter).